# How to find tag by text with regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to get HTML tag by part of its text. I found some solutions but it doesn't work well for me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px; height: 20px">
                <div style="font-size: 8.7pt">
                    Арт.: 
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList2_Label12_0"> 1185A</span>
                    </div>
                <div style="font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;">
                    <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList2_LoginView3_0_Label12_0">I_CAN_GET_THIS other text</span>
                    I CAN NOT GET THIS?.
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
""", 'lxml')
print(soup.find('span', text=re.compile('I_CAN_GET_THIS')))
print(soup.find('div', text=re.compile('I_CAN_NOT_GET_THIS')))

>>> <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList2_LoginView3_0_Label12_0">I_CAN_GET_THIS other text</span>
>>> None
```

So I can;t understand why it doesn't work in the second case and what should I do to make it works? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text` argument (which is now renamed to `string` but is still supported) would use the [`.string` attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) of an element which would become `None` *if there is more than one child*:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None

This is exactly the case with your target `div` element - it has a `span` child and a text node.

Instead, you can locate the text node and then get it's parent:

```
soup.find(text=re.compile('I CAN NOT GET THIS')).parent
```

Or, use a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) where you would use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) which combines children texts:

```
soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and 'I CAN NOT GET THIS' in tag.get_text())
```